# C, read a binary file?

Tags: c, io, binary

I have a binary file that has 309 bytes, I have to read it and then I have to do something with the bits I've got. I'm a beginner in C-programming and using binary files, I know how to read textual files in C, but I don't think binary files uses the same method.

Comment: Perhaps read the manual page for `fopen` and `fread`

Comment: how you could read textual ? reading binary is actually same with reading text file. only difference comes up if you try to print in console. char actually refers byte. so if you get char* from reading text file, you can use same code to read binary file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rb` (read binary) as `mode` parameter in the `fopen()` function.

For more information:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/